# How to get output of HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am exactly expecting is getting the output of HTML stored in one variable using Javascript or Jquery.

```
var htmlTags = "<p>List Heading</p><br/><ol><li>First</li><li>Second</li></ol>"
```

What I want is below output in one variable.

> Expected OUTPUT

```
List Heading

1. First
2. Second
```

I know one trick about this is [innerHTML] but I want this using JS or Jquery as per my need. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hey Bhavik. It seems you're already aware of `innerHTML`, so it's not exactly clear of what you mean by "any help". Instead, kindly share what you've already tried, and describe which portion of the code you're having trouble with. You're more likely to get help if you provide us with something to debug.

Comment: No clue about this. I know one trick about this is [innerHTML] but this is not as per my need. I had searched a lot but didn't get anything

Comment: @TylerRoper I had edited my question. I want to store this one variable.

Comment: `var htmlTags` **is** one variable. Do you want just the text? E.g. `"List Heading First Second"`?

Comment: Edited my question. I want one output in one variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I rendered HTML from the JavaScript file.

```
var html; 

html = `<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-%id%">
        <div class="item__description">%description%</div>
        <div class="right clearfix"> <div class="item__value">%value%</div>
        <div class="item__delete">  <button class="item__delete--btn">
        <i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button> </div></div><div>`
```

In the above code, I've created a div which also contains some dynamic data like **(%value% and %description%)** which is being replaced with real-time user input values.

The output looks like this on the browser [image].